# Swift: Properly initialize SIMD3 and call it from struct

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

I am trying call the defined struct so I am able to change its value when a button is pressed. I am having trouble with calling SIMD3 inside a struct. Currently I have,

```
struct CaptureData {
    var vertices: [SIMD3<Float>]

    var mode: Mode = .one
    mutating func nextCase() {
     mode = mode.next()
    }
    var verticesFormatted : String {

    let v = "<" + vertices.map{ "\($0.x):\($0.y):\($0.z)" }.joined(separator: "~") + "method: \(mode.next().rawValue)"
            return "\(v)"
        }
}
```

And the extension that I got helped earlier from @Joshua

```
enum Mode: String, CaseIterable {
    case one, two, three
}
extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {
    var allCases: AllCases { Self.allCases }
    var nextCase: Self {
        let index = allCases.index(after: allCases.firstIndex(of: self)!)
        guard index != allCases.endIndex else { return allCases.first! }
        return allCases[index]
    }
    @discardableResult
    func next() -> Self {
        return self.nextCase
    }
}
```

I am trying to initialize `var instance = CaptureData(vertices: [SIMD3<Float>])`, but the error comes: `Cannot convert value of type '[SIMD3<Float>].Type' to expected argument type '[SIMD3<Float>]'`

@Jousha also suggested me to use the following:

```
 typealias XYZVar = (x: Float, y: Float, z: Float) 

struct CaptureData { 
var vertices:[XYZVar] 
.... other variables 
}
```

However, I also tried that with `var instance = CaptureData(vertices: [XYZVar])` and it also not working: `Cannot convert value of type '[XYZVar].Type' (aka 'Array<(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float)>.Type') to expected argument type '[XYZVar]' (aka 'Array<(x: Float, y: Float, z: Float)>')`

**My question is, how to I call SIMD3 properly and fix the above error from `var instance = CaptureData(vertices: [SIMD3<Float>])`?**

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, where do I start here?

You are passing `[SIMD3<Float>]` and `[XYZVar]` which are types, to a function/initializer that expects a value as a parameter. That's why the compiler is complaining.

Let me explain.

In swift when you write `var vertices: [SIMD3<Float>]` you are saying: "vertices" is an array of `SIMD3<Float>`. Now, if you want to assign a value to "vertices" you can do so by writing `vertices = []` or `vertices = [SIMD3<Float>]()` they are equivalent.

I did some changes to your code. Take a look:

```swift
    import simd

    enum Mode: String, CaseIterable {
        case one, two, three
    }

    extension CaseIterable where Self: Equatable {

        var allCases: AllCases { Self.allCases }

        var nextCase: Self {
            let index = allCases.index(after: allCases.firstIndex(of: self)!)
            guard index != allCases.endIndex else { return allCases.first! }
            return allCases[index]
        }

        @discardableResult
        func next() -> Self {
            return self.nextCase
        }
    }

    struct CaptureData {
        var vertices: [SIMD3<Float>]

        var mode: Mode = .one

        mutating func nextCase() {
            mode = mode.next()
        }

        var verticesFormatted : String {

            let verticesDescribed = vertices
                .map({ "\($0.x):\($0.y):\($0.z)" })
                .joined(separator: "~")

            let v = "< \(verticesDescribed) method: \(mode.next().rawValue)"

            return v
        }
    }

    let data = CaptureData(vertices: [
        SIMD3<Float>(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0),
        SIMD3<Float>(x: 0.5, y: 1, z: 0),
        SIMD3<Float>(x: 1, y: 0, z: 0)
    ])

    print(data.verticesFormatted) 
    // prints: < 0.0:0.0:0.0~0.5:1.0:0.0~1.0:0.0:0.0 method: two
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I successfully got to method two. If I can ask you a follow up question? I defined var data as you had and used data.nextCase() inside a button. I thought after clicking it the methods will change correspondingly (one, two, then three). However, its only staying with method two throughout...